# LibTiff.net returns null while using Tiff.Open

Tags: c#

```
using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic; 
..
 string filename="image.tif"
 using (Tiff op = Tiff.Open(filename, "w"))
 {
    // do stuff
    op.Close();
 }
 picboxop.Load(filename);
```

This code executes well the first time after debuging, while the second time when the same function is executed it shows a error "System.NullReferenceException". The same code works well on professional visual studio 2010 version. I'm encountering this problem while working on community version of visual studios 2015.

Comment: Which line cause the errors?

Comment: The first line after using(Tiff op=Tiff.Open()), op is shown as null.

Answer (score 0):

One solution i found was to change filename, when the same using function is called with different filename this code seems to work fine.